# Error in regular expression, unable to extract required field from string

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have a string like

```
abcde1234_abcde
```

Using python re, I want to extract `1234_abcde` and the valid string will contain at least 1 number in it followed by `_` *(underscore)*.

When I am using `.*(?P<required>\d+\_.*)` it is giving me `4_abcde` as result not `1234_abcde`

Need help in this.

Comment: `(.*(?P<required>\d+\_.*))` is the regular expression I am using.

Comment: The problem is that `.*` at the beginning is greedy, so it matches the longest possible prefix, and this eats up the first 3 digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution:

```
 re.match(r'.*?(?P<required>\d+\_.*)', 'abcde1234_abcde').group(1)
```

In your original expression, `.*` without `?` after it will try to match as much as it can, so you get the only last digit.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just match:

```
\d+_.*
```

This will match one or more digits `\d+` then an underscore `_`, after that it just captures everything until the end of the string or line.

Your original expression would have worked if you switched from the greedy version of the asterisk to the reluctant *(lazy)* version `*?` like this:

```
 .*?(?P<required>\d+_.*)
```

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/iC5kC2)

Comment: Yes that works, along with search. But trying to find is there any good way of writing regular expression to extract the information.

Comment: @user693079 The way I showed you would be one the best *(if not the best :) )* in this situation.

Comment: +1  Agree with the brief solution. No need to put the `.*` or `.*?` before if you are not using it anyway.

Comment: @beroe Thank you, although the OP doesn't seem to agree with you :)

Comment: Oh well, from the Department of Redundancy Department... (I have two accepted answers with -1 score, so OP is apparently always right  ;^)

Comment: @beroe LOL ! You deserve a +1 for that :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with:

```
\D*(?P<required>\d+_.*)
```